# How to Query ES using Rabbitmq spark stram

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark, stream

I am using Spark2. I am trying to get the stream of search text from Rabbitmq and query againt Elasticsearch.

```
params.put("hosts", "IP");
params.put("queueName", "query");
params.put("exchangeName", "Exchangequery");
params.put("vHost", "/");
params.put("userName", "test");
params.put("password", "test");

Function<byte[], String> messageHandler = new Function<byte[], String>() {

    public String call(byte[] message) {
        return new String(message);
    }
};

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> messages = RabbitMQUtils.createJavaStream(jssc, String.class, params, messageHandler);

messages.foreachRDD();
```

above code receives stram from rabbitmq.  But i am not sure how to connect ES and query for the stream batch. One thing is, If i use   `messages.foreachRDD();` and query the elasticsearch for each input item then it will affect the performance.

Always i will query elasticsearch using only one field. For example

My stram `messages` has the input like

```
apple 
orange
```

i have a index in es `fruit`  and i want to query like `?q=apple or orange`.  I know i have to frame the query using `should` in elasticsearch. ***My question is how can i query against ES using the value received from Rabbitmq stream***

Answer (score 1):

The code makes only one call to the elasticsearch server (basically it constructs a single query with a lot of should clauses)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

    Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));

    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    messages.add("apple");
    messages.add("orange");

    String index = "fruit";
    String fieldName = "fruit_type";

    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

    for (String message : messages) {
        query.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(fieldName, message));
        // alternative if you are not analyzing fields
        // query.should(QueryBuilders.termQuery(fieldName, message));
    }


    int size = 60; //you may want to change this since it defaults to 10
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(query).setSize(size).execute().actionGet();

    long totalHits = response.getHits().getTotalHits();
    System.out.println("Found " + totalHits + " documents");
    for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits()) {
        System.out.println(hit.getSource());
    }
}
```

Query generated:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [ {
      "match" : {
        "fruit_type" : {
          "query" : "apple",
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "match" : {
        "fruit_type" : {
          "query" : "orange",
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem for me is that i want to integrate it with Spark streaming RDD

Comment: would something like this work?      `messages.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
      List<String> fruits = rdd.take(100);
      System.out.println("Fruits: " + fruits);
      for (String message : fruit) {
      //same as above
      }`